# Must the sum of the digits of $n^k$ decrease infinitely often, for $n,k\in\mathbb{N}$ and $n$ not a power of $10$?

Tags: nt.number-theory

This is a (rephrased) repost of a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1102553/on-the-sum-of-digits-of-nk) I asked on MSE about 6 months ago, but didn't receive a definitive answer.

Let $S(n)$ be the sum of the digits of $n$ (in base $10$), is it true that for every $n$ which is not a power of $10$ there are infinitely many $k$ such that $S(n^k)>S(n^{k+1})$? (here $n$ and $k$ are clearly both integers)

The case $n=2$ is answered in [this MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/560624/is-it-true-that-for-infinitely-many-values-of-n-the-sum-of-digits-of-2n-is), what can be said about other values of $n$?

Comment: A similar problem involving varying $n$ and fixed $k$ has been answered by this paper: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1311.0515v2.pdf